# Stability and complexity of some functions

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

Can someone check if my solutions/arguments on this exercise are correct? Thanks!

> Are the following statements true or false?
>
> 1. $\sin (x)=\mathcal{O}(1)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$
> 2. $\sin (x)=\mathcal{O}(1)$ as $x \rightarrow 0$
> 3. $n!=\mathcal{O}((\frac{n}{e})^n)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

I think that the first one is false, because if we approximate the $sin$ function using a truncated taylor series and we substract the real $sin$ function of this, it could still get arbitrarily large.

The second one will be true, i think, by using the same argument as above. Because if we take the limit to $0$, the order will be constant.

For the last one I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your thoughts, part 1 is true: Your argument with the Taylor series does not apply.

Simply use the definition: $\sin (x)=\mathcal{O}(1)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$,
if there is a positive constant $M$ with $|\sin(x)| <= M|1|$ for all $x$ greater than some $x_0$.  In this case you can take $M=1, x_0=0$.

Part 2 uses the same argumentation.

For part 3: Here you can use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_approximation) of the factorial $n!$
which says
$$1 \le \frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac{n}{e})^n} \le \frac{e}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot$$ And this shows that $n!=\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}(\frac{n}{e})^n)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and **not** $n!=\mathcal{O}((\frac{n}{e})^n)$, i.e. part 3 is false.